# How to 3D plot the van der pol equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot in 3D the solution of the van der pol equation with :

- `t` as `x` axis
- `mu` as `y` axis;
- `y(t)` as `z` axis.

I am using [`ode23s`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23s.html) to solve the equation.

My 2D code is :

```
tspan = [0, 6000];
y0 = [1; 1];
Mu = 1000;
ode = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu);
[t,y] = ode23s(ode, tspan, y0);

plot(t,y(:,1))
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y(t)')
```

I would like to have something like this for 3D plot :

```
tspan = [0, 6000];
y0 = [1; 1];
Mu = 1:1000; %Mu variate from 1 to 1000 on the y axis
ode = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu);
[t,y] = ode23s(ode, tspan, y0); %error : Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

plot3(t,Mu,y(:,1))
xlabel('t')
ylabel('mu')
zlabel('y(t)')
```

But this code didn't work, so I tried to put Mu as an argument like this :

```
ode = @(t,y,Mu) vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu)
[t,y,Mu] = ode23s(ode, tspan, y0);
%error : Not enough input arguments
```

But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is probably not correct, because your `vanderpoldemo` function does not implement vectorised evaluation for its `Mu` input.

The second method is not correct, because `ode23s` solves `y' = f(t, y)`, So it does not know what to supply to the third argument.

I guess `Mu` is a parameter in the `vanderpoldemo` function and you do not need to integrate over it. So, what you can do is iterate over all the desired values of `Mu` and calculate the `ode23s` for it as follows:

```
[t, Mu] = meshgrid(0:100:6000, 1:100:1000); %define your desired mesh (trade of between accuracy and computation time)

y = zeros(size(Mu)); % preallocate memory 
y0 = [1; 1];
ode = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu);

% calculate the ode for all the mu values
for i=1:size(Mu, 1)
  [~,y_i] = ode23s(ode, t(i, :), y0);
  y(i, :) = y_i;
end

plot3(t,Mu,y)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('mu')
zlabel('y(t)')
```

Note that I defined the desired evaluation points of `t`, which makes it easier to plot in 3D. Otherwise the sampling of `t` may be different for different values of `Mu`.

Comment: I don't know if it is because I use Jupyter, but I still have the error "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent." after the `ode23`. 

I think it's because of the `t(i,:)` which is `0 100 200 .... 6000` and argument needed in `ode23` would be `0 100` maybe ?

So I tried with one iteration 

`ode = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,1);
[t,y_i] = ode23s(ode, tspan, y0);
y(1, :) = y_i;`

And now I get the error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Comment: Based on the [matlab documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23s.html#inputarg_tspan), you should be able to specify all the intermediate points. I don't know Jupyter, maybe you can check its documentation.